# Google PageSpeed Insights API can't connect to my Wordpress blog to test speed

Tags: wordpress, performance, seo, gtmetrix

Google PageSpeedInsights can't connect to my Wordpress blog URL https://www.siege-gamer.fr/

It says: "Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Un problème est survenu lors de l'enregistrement de la trace du chargement de votre page. Veuillez relancer Lighthouse. (NO_FCP)"

I also have a connection problem with GT Metrix.(Error 403 forbidden).

I sent a technical support request to my web hoster It told it deactivated all my WOrdpress plugins and it worked fine. So there is a problem with one or several of my plugins.

How can I identif which one are the source of this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your website has the closed redirect loop - check the test result from **[Redirect Checker](http://www.redirect-checker.org/)**:

> Result https://www.siege-gamer.fr/ 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>   https://www.siege-gamer.fr 301 Moved Permanently
>
> Problems found: Too many redirects. Please try to reduce your number
>   of redirects for https://www.siege-gamer.fr/. Actually you use 19
>   Redirects. Ideally you should not use more than 3 Redirects in a
>   redirect chain. More than 3 redirections will produce unnecessary load
>   on your server and reduces speed, which ends up in bad user
>   experience.

Comment: I use the WOrdpress plugin "Reall Simple SSL" with .hatacess redirection 301 activated. I just checked the plugin and it says everything is fine.WHat should I do to solve this loop ?